# Assigning properties in an object by iterating through its keys

Tags: typescript

I have an enum:

```
enum REPORT_PARAMETERS {
    DEFECT_CODE = 'DEFECT_CODE',
    ORGANIZATION = 'ORGANIZATION'
}
```

And I have an object and a map of functions, which use this enum as keys:

```
interface Form {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: number;
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: string;
}

const form = {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: 1,
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: '1'
}

const formMappers: {
    [key in REPORT_PARAMETERS]: () => Form[key];
} = {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: () => 123,
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: () => '123'
}
```

Then I want to iterate enum to map form:

```
const reports: REPORT_PARAMETERS[] = [
     REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE,
    REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION
]

reports.forEach((type) => {
  // At this point I assume that 'type' is a specific value of enum,
  // so I try to use this value to index both objects, but it doesn't work
  form[type] = formMappers[type]();
})
```

Here is [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASgogBQPIwCoH0EEEZYLJypwwDKUA3gLABQUdUAInAGJwDCGbSTUAvFAHImrDui5MBAGhr0oKAOJYAcgEkAWllQqkSvoIXL1m7UoE0AvjRoBLEABdgAJwBmAQwDGwKMwD2j6FS0UADa8MhomDj4hMQkAHTC7JzccAC6AFxQ4BAARk4A3DIhYSgY2LgERKRxBqoaWjoZUADOdo62AOaF1JbUNO4%20IK1Qzn7Q-IF0oYilkRUx1Ymi4mmZAIzSQdPhZVGVsTUwinXGjZkCa2Y9VtQDQ3YjY3iuAA4vTs2Zk-TBANbAAE8oLZYDMIuVolUSE0ABQASj4AD5vGM-oDUt1zHpvttZhD9osWEkxClYQjeMi1gAmADMmymJXBewW8VqRgaSjJSME1JpV16-UGw0cwBefjsn1BOzmkNiwVSemCRXojN28yhCSJyxS9JVYLVsuqbPqJhoqRuIrFjglcVGjjgHgAFjCYXYAe9ycjvnaIME3e8Ffwfc83h8-e7gKl4Zi4UA) to see it in action

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with enums; you can dispense with enums and see [the same behavior](https://tsplay.dev/wO8LMN).

Comment: @jcalz how would you name it then? Should I rename it?

Comment:  Maybe "assigning properties in an object by iterating through its keys" or something?  Not sure.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38735](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38735) and [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED after @jcalz comment**

This is classical example.

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) you can find official explanation.

> When an indexed access T[K] occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by T[K], but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type of the properties selected by T[K]. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.

Error:

> Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

means that `string & number` resolves to `never` because it is impossible to represent such type.

If you want to fix it, you need to avoid mutation:

```js
enum REPORT_PARAMETERS {
  DEFECT_CODE = 'DEFECT_CODE',
  ORGANIZATION = 'ORGANIZATION'
}

interface Form {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: number;
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: string;
}

const form = {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: 1,
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: '1'
}

const formMappers: {
  [key in REPORT_PARAMETERS]: () => Form[key];
} = {
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE]: () => 123,
  [REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION]: () => '123'
}

const reports: REPORT_PARAMETERS[] = [
  REPORT_PARAMETERS.DEFECT_CODE,
  REPORT_PARAMETERS.ORGANIZATION
]

const result = reports.reduce((acc, type) => ({
  ...acc,
  [type]: formMappers[type]()

}), form)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=33&pln=26&pc=2#code/KYOwrgtgBASgogBQPIwCoH0EEEZYLJypwwDKUA3gLABQUUAInAGJwDCGrSjUAvFAOSMW7dJ0b8ANDTooA4lgByASQBaWVEqQLeAuYtXrNC-jQC%20NGgEsQAF2AAnAGYBDAMbAoTAPb3oVWlAA2vDIaJg4%20ITEJAB0QmwcXHAAugBcUOAQAEYOANzSQSEoGNi4BESkMXrKahpaaVAAzjb21gDm%20dTm1DSuXiDNUI4%200Hz%20dMGIxeFlUZXxImIp6QCMUgGToSUR5dFVMPI1hvXp-CsmXRbUfQM2QyN4zgAOTw6N6eNBANbAAJ5Q1lgUzCpUiFRIDQAFABKXgAPk8I0CP1%20yU6ph0n0201Bu3mzASoiSUNhPARKwATABmdYTIognZzWLVAx1BQk%20ECSlUi7dXr9Qb2YBPHw2d5ArYzMHRQLJHSBAr07azcFxAmLJK0iU4xmqlm1Iw0ZJXG6C4CNMAAGzufCFIvsYpiQoAJmB3JDIW5XBIoDZfq9SQjIZ8YqGvVrAn7Xg1hr5Hi83pH-cBkjCrqZoT7YxBoUA)

You can find more information about mutations in typescript in [my blog](https://catchts.com/mutations)

Comment: "It resolves to intersection because objects are contravariant in their key types." Is this right? When you *read* an object from a union of key types, you get a *union* of property types, so `keyof` contravariance seems to be irrelevant here.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, it totally worked for me!