# TypeScript does not work correctly when iterating over the keys of an object

Tags: typescript

I have simple code (TS v4.5.4):

```
type P = {
  n1: number,
  n2: string,
};
const p1 = {
  n1: 10,
  n2: '10',
} as P;
const p2 = {
  n1: 10,
  n2: '10',
} as P;
const pkeys = Object.keys(p1) as Array<keyof P>;
pkeys.forEach((key) => {
  p1[key] = p2[key];
});
```

But on the penultimate line the typescript says:

Type 'string | number 'is not assignable to type' never '.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts (2322)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations). I believe that your question is a duplicate of one of these: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773327/assigning-properties-in-an-object-by-iterating-through-its-keys/68773501#68773501), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576735/keyof-and-react-redux-action/68578198#68578198), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521780/cannot-dynamically-set-interface-objects-property-values/68526031#68526031), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576735/keyof-and-react-redux-action/68578198#68578198)

Comment: Please let me know if these answers works for you