# TypeScript: Typing a value based on an object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, types

I need some help on my TypeScript adventure.

Here's my example type:

```js
type Target = {
  names: string[]
  addresses: {
      location: string
    }[]
};
```

Here's my example object:

```js
const myTarget: Target = {
  names: ["Alex", "Nico"],
  addresses: [
    {
      location: "Miami",
    },
    {
      location: "New York",
    },
  ],
};
```

And here's my function example:

```js
const changeValue = (
    key: keyof Target,
    value: string | Record<string, unknown>
) => {
 myTarget[key] = [...myTarget[key], value]
}

changeValue('names', 'Elvis')
changeValue('addresses', { location: "Atlanta" })
```

I've an error on the `myTarget[key]` saying this:

> Cannot assign type '(string | Record<string, unknown>)[]' to type 'string[] & { location: string; }[]'.
> Cannot assign type '(string | Record<string, unknown>)[]' to type 'string[]'.
> Cannot assign type 'string | Record<string, unknown>' of type 'string'.
> Cannot assign type 'Record<string, unknown>' to type 'string'
> .ts(2322)

From what I understand is that, for example, TypeScript is testing all combinations, including adding an object  to the `names` array, which is invalid, or adding a string inside `addresses` array.

Can someone please help me to understand what's the problem and how can I handle it. ( the real project is so much more complicated, but maybe with this example I'll understand a bit..)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, where you want to pass a key of an object type and a value of the type of that key, you can do so like this:

```
const changeValue = <K extends keyof Target, V extends Target[K]>(
    key: K,
    value: V
) => {
 myTarget[key] = value; 
}
```

That is, you tell the compiler that `value` is not only the same type of some value of the object, but the same type as the one given by `key`.

However, you upped the difficult by playing with arrays.  There is not, so far as I know, a utility type to extract the type of an array, so I wrote one:

```
type ArrayType<T> = T extends Array<infer U>? U : never;
```

Now we can use it:

```
const appendValue = <K extends keyof Target, V extends ArrayType<Target[K]>>(
    key: K,
    value: V
) => {
 myTarget[key] = [...myTarget[key], value] as Target[K];
}
```

Unfortunately, as you see, the compiler gets a little confused about the relationship between `V[]` and `Target[K]`, so it needs the hint in the form of `as`.

Now the calls compile cleanly:

```
appendValue('names', 'Elvis')
appendValue('addresses', { location: "Atlanta" })
```

Incidentally, you do some things in your example code (though perhaps not in your actual code) that I would urge you not to do.

First, you have [mutable global data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148109/7397), `myTarget`.  *Hic fons lacrimis*, do not do this, in any language, if you can at all avoid it.

Also, mutating data in general is [a bad idea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huIHUim76AM).  Consider this instead:

```
const appendValue = <K extends keyof Target, V extends ArrayType<Target[K]>>(
    target: Target,
    key: K,
    value: V
): Target => ({
    ...target,
    [key]: [...myTarget[key], value] as Target[K]
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That's quite a lot of new concept that you use but I'll try to get used to them.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you have an error ?**

Answer on this question you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68773327/assigning-properties-in-an-object-by-iterating-through-its-keys/68773501#68773501) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576735/keyof-and-react-redux-action/68578198#68578198) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521780/cannot-dynamically-set-interface-objects-property-values/68526031#68526031) and in my article [here](https://catchts.com/mutations).

Using this type `string | Record<string, unknown>` for `value` argument is not safe. It is better to infer the type of `key` argument:

```js
const changeValue = <Key extends keyof Target>(
    key: Key,
    value: Target[Key][number]
) => {
    // error
    myTarget[key] = [...myTarget[key], value]
}
```

You have an error here, because there is no correlation (inside) function body between `key` and `value`. Such correlation exists only outisde of function, I mean, when you call this function.

Please keep in mind that `key` is still a union type.
I think it worth using immutable approach:

```js
type Target = {
    names: string[]
    addresses: {
        location: string
    }[]
};

const myTarget: Target = {
    names: ["Alex", "Nico"],
    addresses: [
        {
            location: "Miami",
        },
        {
            location: "New York",
        },
    ],
};


const withTarget = <
    Obj extends Record<string, unknown[]>
>(target: Obj) => <
    Key extends keyof Obj
>(
    key: Key,
    value: Obj[Key][number]
): Obj => ({
    ...target,
    [key]: target[key].concat(value)
})

const changeValue = withTarget(myTarget);
const result = changeValue('names', 'Elvis')
```